# Convert all IF formulas (TRUE) into values except the rows containing an IF formula (FALSE)

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am interested in doing this: IF Cell C14 = Cell $C$8, THEN keep the cell value BUT remove the IF formula. For rest of the Cells in Column C with IF Formula (False condition: "InsertText!"), retain the IF formula

[Refer to Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEvvj.png)
I've tried multiple ways of phrasing the VBA syntax but I'm not getting the desired result.

```
Sub convertToValue()
    Dim totRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
'   Find row with word InsertText in it
    totRow = Cells.Find(What:="InsertText", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Row
    Set rng = Rows("C:C")
    rng.Copy
    rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, Transpose:=False
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: So this formula is either displaying the value of C14 or some constant text "InsertText!"?  And you want to replace the values of all the formulas that aren't equal to the constant text "InsertText!" with their values?  If you use the auto filter to show anything except that constant text "InsertText!" then you can Copy and Paste Special: Values those cells to get rid of the formulas just for the filtered cells.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEvvj.png  Hi Jerry thanks for the reply! Yes you've got it partially right. But the issue is that the value in $C$8 changes with the value in another cell (vlookup). Because there are over 1000 products for review, the easier way is to have the details entered in the yellow box and reflected in the columns below using the IF formula. Once the new details are captured, I want the end-user to click a button that runs a macro to remove the IF formula for that cell.

Comment: So when $C$2 is chosen, you fill in New Details in $C$8. Then you would Copy and then Paste Special: Values any cell in C below 13 that isn't "Insert Text!" - but it isn't automatic. And then you have to repeat 1000 times?! I see why you want it optimised. I think a VBA solution might be the only choice. Do you have a sheet with a list of all 1000 products and their New Details or do you have to enter that data manually? If doing it manually, I wouldn't use a selection change event because you might accidentally change it and not mean to - a button (Developer tab, Insert) would be better.

Comment: Yes exactly! Yep the products are coming from another tab using PowerQuery because the old details are being updated by multiple users. (and they are coming from disparate sources) 

New details are entered manually by someone else (who's not much of an Excel person). But the end goal is to have the 1000 columns populated without the IF formulas and have them sent for review. 

I'm still learning the ropes of VBA so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try this and see if it does what you want.  If not we will try something else:
`Sub convertToValue()`
`Range("13:13").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>Insert Text", Operator:=xlAnd`
`Range("C8").Copy`
`Range("C:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Find(What:="*", After:=ActiveSheet.Range("C13"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate`
`Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select`
`ActiveSheet.Paste`
`Range("13:13").AutoFilter Field:=3`
`Range("C3").Select`
`End Sub`

Comment: PasteSpecial: Values doesn't work properly with AutoFilter - normally if you select some cells in a filtered section and Paste only the visible cells are replaced, but PasteSpecial: Values replaces ALL values including those that are not visible. So that's a problem with my idea to use AutoFilter.  If copying the cell format and everything is ok it might work but I suspect you only want to replace the formulas.  We may need to loop through each individual row...

Comment: If column C always contains "Insert Text" or the value in $C$8 then we could look for the value of $C$8 instead of looking for cells that don't contain "Insert Text".  I guess it depends if that's always true or not...

Comment: I think this works better than the AutoFilter method because this way you can do a PasteSpecial: Values.  What do you think? 
`Sub convertToValue()`
`LastRow = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row`
`For Row = 13 To LastRow`
`Set CurrentCell = Range("C" & Row)`
`If CurrentCell.Value2 <> "Insert Text" Then`
`Range("C8").Copy`
`CurrentCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`
`End If`
`Next`
`Range("C3").Select`
`End Sub`

Comment: Hmm both didn't work:( For the previous one I'm getting an error near the For Row = 13. Should there be a ActiveCell.Formula somewhere or that's not necessary?

Comment: Did it say what the error was?  Perhaps you have two of the commands on the same line instead of having each one on its own line - VBA hates that (although you can put a colon between commands to allow that).  Putting code in commands never seems to work well. Maybe I should write it as an answer - I didn't want to do that until I was sure it would work but it might help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me with my test spreadsheet.

```
Sub convertToValue()
    LastRow = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    ' change the 13 in the line below to whichever row the data
    ' actually starts on (the one after the table header)
    For Row = 13 To LastRow
        Set CurrentCell = Range("C" & Row)
        ' do the copy/paste only if the current cell is a
        ' formula AND it doesn't evaluate to "Insert Text"
        If Left(CurrentCell.Formula, 1) = "=" And CurrentCell.Value2 <> "Insert Text" Then
            Range("C8").Copy
            CurrentCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next
    Range("C3").Select
End Sub
```

If you assign it to a button then you can set the product, enter new details, push the button, and repeat.

Comment: Oh yes that's great it works now! The .Row was in the same row  (pun unintended) as For Row. But when I just ran the macro, it now searches for every cell that does not contain the IF Formula and pastes the same value in C8, overriding the previous value. Is there a way to add another condition to the IF part so that it skips those cells (without the IF formula AND does not match c8), pasting only the value for the current one that matches C8?

Comment: @isalexis  So you want it to skip it if it isn't a formula and replace only formulas.  I think we can do that.